# Why is there no "exists" functions within C++ map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, language-features

I find myself sometimes checking to see if an item already exists in a `std::map`, which I do with the following:

```
if(myMap.find(item) != myMap.end()) ...
```

I was wondering why there is not a function such as `exists()` which would return the same bool of whether the item is already in the map.

It would save a bit of typing, but more importantly it would seem to be far clearer:

```
if(myMap.exists(item)) ...
```

Comment: You can use `myMap.count(item)`. `count` returns 1 or 0, which is effectively a boolean true or false when used in an if condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since C++20 you can use [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains).

> **Return value**
>
> `true` if there is such an element, otherwise `false`.

```
if(myMap.contains(item)) ...
```